# JavaScript this.todoList.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, sharepoint, vuejs2

I want to create a ToDo list in Vue.js, but the items don't show up. (When I use localStorage to store the items it works, but when I use a list on SharePoint it doesn't)

[image]

The problem is most likely this part (since I adapted the code):

```
computed: {
            pending: function () {
              console.log("pending");
              if (!this.todoList) {
                return [];
              }
              return this.todoList.filter((item) => !item.done);
            }
```

I get the ToDo list items using a `getToDos` method:

```
 methods: {
            getTodos() {
              let siteUrl = 'https://thesite.sharepoint.com/sites/Playercard/';
              var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
              var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('PhysicalGoals');
              var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
              var playerID = this.$store.state.selectedPlayer.ID;
              console.log("playerID getTodos: " + playerID);
              camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'playerID\'/>' +
                      '<Value Type=\'Text\'>'+playerID+'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');

              collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
              clientContext.load(collListItem);

              clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededNew),
                      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedNew)
              );
            },
            onQuerySucceededNew(){
              console.log("onQuerySucceededNew!");
              var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

              while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                this.todoList = oListItem.get_item('Title');
                console.log("this.todoList: " + this.todoList);
              }
              console.log("this.todoList: " + this.todoList);
              console.log("this.todoList.toString(): " + this.todoList.toString());
              console.log("this.todoList.length): " + this.todoList.length);

            }
```

I think the problem is `item`, but I don't know how I have to adapt the code. 
It is a single file component with HTML, CSS and JS. 
Here's the [full component](https://pastebin.com/71jwHwjm).

Does someone know how one can fix this issue?

Comment: I'm sure the issue is not in the `pending` computed property. The issue is `this.todoList` is not an array.

Comment: In the console logs you can see, It's a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

- The error is indicating that `todoList` exists but is not an array so has no `filter` method.  If `todoList` did not exist at all, the computed would have returned `[]` without an error.
- When you set `todoList`, you do so in a loop where it is overwritten multiple times.

**Fix**

Try changing `onQuerySucceededNew` to:

```js
onQuerySucceededNew(){
  console.log("onQuerySucceededNew!");
  var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

  const todoList = [];  // New array to hold items

  while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    todoList.push(oListItem.get_item('Title'));  // add item instead of ovewriting
    console.log("this.todoList: " + this.todoList);
  }

  this.todoList = todoList;  // set the component data property

  console.log("this.todoList: " + this.todoList);
  console.log("this.todoList.toString(): " + this.todoList.toString());
  console.log("this.todoList.length): " + this.todoList.length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it.
It does tell me now that there are 3 items (which is correct), but it doesn't list them up: https://imgur.com/a/ZTPykx0
Do you know what the cause of that is?

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the feedback.  To understand why they're not shown in the template, we'll need to see the template code.  Feel free to edit your post to include that.  Or you can just copy this to the template:  `<div v-for="(item, index) in todoList" :key="index">{{ item }}</div>`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in the `onQuerySucceededNew()` function. You have to push items in to an array.

Example solution:

```
onQuerySucceededNew(){
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        this.todoList.push(oListItem.get_item('Title'));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

And make sure to define `this.todoList` as an array in the component.

```
data() {
    return {
        todoList: [],
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the condition like this

```
pending: function () {
   console.log("completed");
   if (this.todoList && this.todoList.length>0) {
     return this.todoList.filter(item => !item.done);
   }
   return [];
}
```

Note: make sure the data in `this.todoList` assigning correctly and it is in `array` format.